# How extend ElementView in jointJS using typescript?

Tags: typescript, jointjs

JointJS is looking for ElementView in the same namespace as Element (joint.shapes.org.NewRectView near joint.shapes.org.NewRect) but it doesn't work when I write it with modules in typescript.

```
    module joint{  
        module shapes{
             module org{
                 class NewRect{
                     ...
                 }
                 class NewRectView{
                     ...
                 }
             }
        }
    }
```

HowI can fix it and repair default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

> HowI can fix it and repair default behavior?

If you do not have a `declare` keyword before your `module` (like the .d.ts does : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jointjs/jointjs.d.ts#L9-L11) then you need to *`export`* anything you want to make available to a split definition of a module. So:

```
module joint{  
    export module shapes{
         export module org{
             export class NewRect{
                 ...
             }
             export class NewRectView{
                 ...
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry. I think it is not important for this case. I used "export" as you wrote, but it did not change anything.